# Plotting function in R

Tags: r

I have variables in dataframe and I am trying to build a function that allows me to plot a variable in a data without redudantly writing, `data$variablename`.

```
plt=function(x){
    plot(data$date,as.name(paste("data$",x,sep="")),type="l",xlab="Population",ylab="Time")
}
```

R keeps thinking that my y-variable is a name rather than a variable. How do I tell it that the y-axis input in the function `plot` is a name rather than the actual variable?

Comment: Use `[` to specify the y variable instead. `data[, x]` perhaps.

Comment: I was unware you could call on variable like that. I tried entering `data[,population] ` and `data[,data$population] ` it gives me "object" not found error.

Comment: Try `data[, "population"]` instead. See `?Extract` for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like the following (two options provided--the uncommented one would be my preferred approach):

```
plt <- function(x, data = mydf) {
  x <- deparse(substitute(x))
# with(data, plot(date, get(x), type = "l", xlab = "Population", ylab = "Time"))
  plot(data[, "date"], data[, x], type = "l", xlab = "Population", ylab = "Time")
}
```

When using `data[, x]`, `x` needs to be a character vector, hence the use of `deparse(substitute(x))` in the first line of the function. Thus, you would enter the y column unquoted. I've also added a "`data`" argument to let you specify which dataset you are dealing with.

Try the function out with this:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(date = 1:100, A = rnorm(100), B = rnorm(100), C = rnorm(100))

plt(A)
plt(B)
plt(C)
```